# Strange behaviour when trying to send data with ajax (jQuery)

Tags: php, ajax, litespeed

I'm coding an website which must have same functionality as SO. My server use Litespeed, which increase the speed of runing php files.

When I'm trying to send php code in regular form, everything seems to be ok, data being sent to the action file without interpreting the code inside the variable. But when I'm trying to send the same data in comments textareas, with jQuery `$.post` method, I'm getting **Forbidden 403** error. Data is blocked on the road by Litespeed server. I don't know why is happening this, why is `$_POST` data auto-evaluated when using ajax?

This situation doesn't appear everytime, but just in some cases, for example:

```
this is a new message which presents this php code: <?php mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table"); ?>
```

Note that if I remove `<?php` and `?>` from my message, it is ok. I've already tried to use `encodeURI()` method but this don't change anything.

Is there any setting which must be applied in `.htaccess` for not auto-evaluate $_POST data?

or I should replace the open and close tags, before sending the comment?

**Later edit**

This is how I managed to resolve this right now, but I'm still waiting for a suggestion with `.htaccess`:

```
$but.prev('textarea').val().replace(/(<\?php)/gi,'-?php ').replace(/(<\?)/gi,'-? ').replace(/\?>/gi,' ?-');
```

and on the server side

```
str_replace(array('-?php','?-','-?'), array('`<?php','?>`','`<?'), $_POST['comment']);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "auto-evaluate", can you clarify? Also if a 403 occurs, you should be getting a message in the error log about what is wrong?

Comment: I've already chechekd error logs and there is no useful information. I mean that the server interprets it as a php code, not as a plain text content, and that's why it blocks it